# SQL Server Join a result with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do the following operation.

- Join 2 tables => obtain a result

The result of the 1st join i need it to join on another table

Here is what I have

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, T2.*
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM ProductPackType ppt
     JOIN ProductPack pp ON ppt.ProductPackTypeID = pp.ProductPackTypeID
     WHERE pp.Acronym = 'IS') AS T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM PRODUCT) AS T2 ON T1.ProductPackID = T2.ProductPackID
```

This is the error message

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The column 'Name' was specified multiple times for 'T1'

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have columns with name "Name" in both ProductPackType and ProductPack?

Comment: yep, the 2 have a column named "Name"

Comment: Do you really need both these columns in result? You should avoid equal names in such queries. Try to enumeate columns you need manually and set to them unique names

Comment: nop, i just solve the issue, thx dude you really helped me out here, i didn't thought that this could be an issue , actually i never thought of it at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the column Name in both ProductPackType and ProductPack tables. Try something like:

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, T2.*
FROM 
    (SELECT ppt.Name, pp.Name as ppName --add the rest of your wanted columns...
     FROM ProductPackType ppt
     JOIN ProductPack pp ON ppt.ProductPackTypeID = pp.ProductPackTypeID
     WHERE pp.Acronym = 'IS') AS T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM PRODUCT) AS T2 ON T1.ProductPackID = T2.ProductPackID
```

As you can see, i am trying to avoid having in the T1 table resulted from the joined query two columns with the name 'Name' (weird word game here).

You can even write something shorter like:

```
SELECT ppt.*, pp.Name as ppName --and the rest of the pp columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not forget all the subquery stuff and just join the tables together?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ProductPackType ppt
JOIN ProductPack pp ON ppt.ProductPackTypeID = pp.ProductPackTypeID
JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.ProductPackID = ppt.ProductPackID
WHERE pp.Acronym = 'IS'
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have "name" from "ppt" and "pp", try the following

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, T2.*
FROM 
    (SELECT ppt.*, pp.*
     FROM ProductPackType ppt
     JOIN ProductPack pp ON ppt.ProductPackTypeID = pp.ProductPackTypeID
     WHERE pp.Acronym = 'IS') AS T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM PRODUCT) AS T2 ON T1.ProductPackID = T2.ProductPackID
```

Comment: ppt.*, pp .* is equal * and it will not work too. TC has to replace * with all columns and rename those columns that has equal names.